# Azure data upload and SQL database update failure for filename tracking

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I have a scenario, in which I upload the file to Azure and will get the uploaded filename. Now I would need to store the filename (received for Azure upload) to SQL database.

In case, if database down means it will fail to capture the filename (received for Azure upload) to SQL database but the File upload to Azure was successful.

Here, how can I update the filename (received for Azure upload) to SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the filename to your Azure SQL Database whenever you upload new blob in Storage account using **Azure Logic App.**

Create Logic App service using Azure Portal. [Follow link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow).

Once it is created, **Go to the resource**. Click on **Logic App Designer** and select **Blank Logic App**.

Search for **when blob is added or modified** and select it.

[image]

Give the **connection name, storage account name and storage account access key** to connect your storage account. Click **Create**.

[image]

Fill the details to connect your container. **Fill other required details to run your logic app automatically after given interval time.** Click on **+ Next Step**.

[image]

Search for **SQL Server** and select. Fill the required details to connect with your SQL Server. Click **Create.**

[image]

In the next step, select the **server, database and table**. Also **select the column name in which you want to store the filenames**. In the selected column name, select **List of Files DisplayName**. This will capture the filenames you uploaded in the container.

[image]

Lastly, click on **Save -> Run Trigger -> Run** to run your app login.

Simply, add any blob in your container and it's filename will be added in your SQL Database. Check below for reference.

[image]